# Checkbox CheckedChanged not working properly

Tags: asp.net

i'm making a .aspx page with a checkbox that when it was checked it have to change the visibility of a radio list.
When i check it, the radio list was shown but when i uncheck it, the radio list don't disappears.
So, my code is that:

**Front-end:**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbProspect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
                            oncheckedchanged="ckbProspect_CheckedChanged" />
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbListProspect" runat="server" Visible="false" 
                            AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Sim"></asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="Não"></asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

**Back-end**

```
protected void ckbProspect_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rbListProspect.Visible = ckbProspect.Checked;
}
```

How can i fix that and what it's wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add "AutoPostBack=true" to the asp control?

Comment: @Op as far as i see your code , they are fine and even they are working accordingly in my VS2015 , i will suggest you to make it a new site in visual studio and test it as a new.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ckbProspect" runat="server" Checked="false"
    OnCheckedChanged="ckbProspect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

*P.S:* I believe there's nothing wrong with your code, it's working just fine.

[image: outp]

Comment: When i check it, the radio list appears. But when i uncheck it, the radio list don't disappears.

Comment: When i check the checkbox, radio list have to appear. And when i uncheck the checkbox, radio list have to disappears.

Comment: @LucasS.Müller the code that you have written it alright and it is even working fine in my VS2015. I dont understand why it is not behaving according in your system.

Comment: It's inside a Update Panel: `<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upAtividades" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" RenderMode="Block">`. But even i putting `upAtividades.Update();` in code behind it don't work.